# time delay on jQuery add class

Tags: jquery, class, triggers, delay

I currently have a CSS3 animation that is triggered by adding a class once the window scrolls to a certain point. I'd like to add a delay of 1 second so the animation doesn't start strait away. Here is the page where the animation takes place:

http://www.lindameredith.com/wp/serum/ (scroll to second section)

The existing code i'm using is:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function playani() {
  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  //add 'ok' class when div position match or exceeds else remove the 'ok' class.
  jQuery('#angle').addClass('play', scroll >= jQuery('#angle').offset().top);
});
```

Does anyone know how to adjust this to add a delay?

thank you :)

Comment: You couldn't  just add a delay to your animation ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: @soywod Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: you can use jquery basic fadein or fadeout as you want and add as parameters the time jQuery('#angle').addClass('play', scroll >= jQuery('#angle').offset().top).fadein(1000); delay 1s this is a setTimeout but 100% jquery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delay jQuery `.addClass()` by 1s:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   jQuery('selector').addClass('className');
}, 1000);
```

To [delay CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) by 1s:

```
.animated {
    /* other animation properties */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```